# How to keep procedural texture proportion automatically

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, texture-coordinates

If I add a procedural texture into node Compositor, it became oval, because of Render's aspect ration.

Does exist a way to math a value for Texture > Scale input socket, that take Render aspect ratio into account to correct deformed proportion of texture?

I was able to manually stretch it back with Scale node > Absolute, but it doesn't seem to be the best way for texture quality.

[image]
[image]

I would prefer correct "Scale" on texture node **input** socket automatically when Render size is changed. (Sorry for different texture type here, I hope its not confusing.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be best to perform the scale at the texture node, this way the quality will be better than doing it after the texture is generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For best quality Scale the texture via texture node the input vector. Use a Combine RGB node to send the correct values. Assuming that the width =1.0. Divide the height by the width for the width factor. e.g. (1080/1920), this will reset the aspect. Use a color curve to scale the vector.

[image: rectify texture aspect]

To save you having to type in the current scene dimensions you can set them as a driver in a Value node.
First, here is the wrong aspect which Blender simply "fits" to the current aspect, in this example the scene is 16:9 while the texture is 1:1.

[image: Fitted aspect]

Add 2 Value nodes

[image: add value nodes]

Right click in each node value window and select Add Driver > single from target.

[image: Add driver]

Use the proper to choose the scene dimensions.

[image: select driver source]

Add a Math Node and set it to divide, then divide the width by the height.

[image: divide dimensions]

The X aspect is sent to the vector input via the green register, correcting the distortion of the texture.

[image: aspect corrected]

You can add another Math node set to multiply and a Value node to scale the texture after correction.

[image: scale texture by vector]

Result

[image: scaled result]

**UPDATE**

To re-use the aspect correction you can collect them into a Group Node. *Beware that the drivers (in groups) fail if you change dimensions of the scene*. If you need them to be dynamic then I suggest just copy and pasting the collected set of nodes, excluding the texture node of course.

Select the Value, Math and Combine RGB nodes and press Ctrl G to set them as a group.

[image: Make group]

Press the Tab key to step out of the group node and label it so that you can locate it later.

[image: name group]

To add the group elsewhere in your nodes, Add a node and choose node group > (your node group name)

[image: add group]

Attach it to your texture.

[image: add to texture]

Remember that drivers will fail inside a group node, so they cannot change dynamically.

Comment: Thank you, scale texture with RGB is cool - its directly updated, changing texture size in texture prop. panel I need to go frame +/-. BUT ... anytime i change aspect ration of render I need to divide size again. I want to let nodes math it automatically. I want to save a node group with Vignette. Anytime I append the group I want to connect it without care what current aspect ratio render use. SO ... Is there a way to let some nodes read size of render from render properties panel?

Comment: Just stick math in front of the RGB combine node. I didn't, just for speed of reply. EDIT: Oh I see... you might be able to access the scene dimensions as a driver value but drivers in Nodes are notoriously flaky. You might have to set a scene variable as a Value node at the start, sorry.